# Asynchronous JavaScript execution order?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Asynchronous JS has always been a bit confusing for me...

I have this example code:

```js
function asyncFunction() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    })
};

function example() {
    asyncFunction().then(
        output => {
            for (element of output) {
                console.log(element + ", A") //This should be displayed first
            }
        }
    )
};

example();

console.log('B'); //But it isn't
```

Which produces the following output:

```
B
1, A
2, A
3, A
4, A
5, A
```

Is there a way to program this so that B will be printed after the As? I'm actually using an RSS feed parser module here, the above is just an example to illustrate the problem.

Comment: `console.log('B');` would need to be included in the `then` function because non-async code will always be executed before async code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling `asyncFunction` returns a Promise. Even if the Promise resolves immediately, any `.then`s chained onto it will be put into the microtask queue, whose tasks will only start running once all other *synchronous* code has finished.

Since `console.log('B');` runs synchronously after the `example` call, `B` will be printed before the `.then` callback runs.

If you want to be sure B gets logged after all array elements are logged, return the `asyncFunction` promise from `example`, then call `.then` on it, and log `B` inside that `.then`'s callback:

```js
function asyncFunction() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    })
};

function example() {
    return asyncFunction().then(
        output => {
            for (element of output) {
                console.log(element + ", A") //This should be displayed first
            }
        }
    )
};

example().then(() => {
  console.log('B'); //But it isn't
});
```

Comment: It's described in [`HostEnqueuePromiseJob`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-hostenqueuepromisejob), which basically says: "run this function at some future time".

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises — “To avoid surprises, functions passed to then() will never be called synchronously, even with an already-resolved promise..”

Comment: I forgot to mention this, but there's an additional complicating factor with this.

Comment: @Tee1er What is the complicating factor?

Comment: @CertainPerformance There is an array of objects representing RSS feeds, and the asynchronous function (parsing the feed) needs to be run on each one. After all of the feeds have been parsed, the rest of the program should be run, although a callback of some sort would probably be fine. The `.forEach()` (or `for/of`) seems to be the complicating factor in this case.

Comment: @Tee1er Use `Promise.all` instead: `Promise.all(output.map(parseElement)).then(mainProgram)` where `parseElement` returns the asynchronous parsing